# Vs 2008 Win Forms Designer Issue

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, version-control, c#-3.0

*Disclaimer - The Tools I'm using are:*

- Visual Studio 2008
- C#/.Net  (version 3.5)
- An external set of controls

*Additional disclaimer: I'm not asking for help with the external set of controls, just if anyone has experience anything similar to this, or if they have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue*

Hi all,

I've been building a mock-up program in C#, using an external library of controls as and when I need extra functionality (I'll name the extra controls if it'll help) over the past few weeks.

As with all the projects I work on (personal or for work), I check in after I add any code or make any changes to the UI - obviously, I include a commit comment, too.

The UI consists of 3 panels, each with 1 or more groups. Each of the groups has 1 or more control on them. I'm disabling and hiding the irrelevant controls as the user walks through the UI. this is the approach I'm taking in the mock-up/demo version of the program, I'll be re-implementing it when it goes from this stage (pre-development/UI design) to the next stage (actual development of the logic and minor UI refinement)

I've come up against an issue in the past few weeks. If I have the code base and the designer view open in Visual Studio, and I make a change to the code base (however small or large), when I switch back to the designer view I get the following error:

> The designer loader did not provide a root component but has not indicated why.
>   Instances of this error (1)
>   1.   There is no stack trace or error line information available for this error

As this has only happened recently (within the past week), I'm thinking that it's related to one of the controls that I've added or removed.

Side note: The boss had me completely redesign the UI, but he decided to do a CTRL-A, CRTL-X just before hand, and I'm not sure the undo command completed correctly. I did, check in just before he "tested" the UI, and checked back out when I thought the undo command didn't complete correctly - something I've learnt to do as the boss start moving things around, or playing with the code whenever he comes over to check on the progress.

I've found a temporary solution, but it's a little annoying. The temporary solution takes the following form:

1. Close the designer view
2. Re-open the designer view

And voila, it works. but I have to remember to do that every time that I make a change to the code base - if the designer view is already open.

Has anyone got any useful suggestions for what I could do to solve this issue (the designer issue, not the boss taking a "proactive approach to UI design") ?